# Pipe tests/traces from Gambit Scheme Interpreter to file

Tags: scheme, pipe, gambit

If I procedure, example:

```
(define square
  (lambda (n)
    (* n n)))
```

and I test it using (square 5) for example, how do I pipe this result from the Gambit Scheme interpreter to a text file?

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
(define square
  (lambda (n)
     (* n n)))

(call-with-output-file "a-file.txt"
  (lambda ()
     (display (square 5))
     (newline)))
```

Another is to print directly to standard output:

```
(define square
  (lambda (n)
     (* n n)))

(display (square 5))
(newline)
```

And then use `>` in the shell to direct the output to a specific file.